# Android NDK Build command not recognized error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building libopus using ndk for my application but when I build I get this error:

```
 Error:Note: D:\VoiceRecorderCopy(7)\opuslib\src\main\java\top\oply\opuslib\OpusPlayer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':opuslib:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\we\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\VoiceRecorderCopy(7)\opuslib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\VoiceRecorderCopy(7)\opuslib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=D:/VoiceRecorderCopy(7)/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\VoiceRecorderCopy(7)\opuslib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib D:/VoiceRecorderCopy(7)/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/mips64/libopustool.so}
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= bands.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= celt.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= celt_encoder.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= celt_decoder.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= cwrs.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= entcode.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= entdec.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= entenc.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= kiss_fft.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= laplace.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= mathops.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= mdct.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= modes.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= pitch.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= celt_lpc.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= quant_bands.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= rate.c
[mips64] Compile        : opustool <= vq.c
'D:\VoiceRecorderCopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [D:/VoiceRecorderCopy(7)/opuslib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/mips64/objs/opustool/celt/arm/armcpu.o] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This is how I defined in build.gradle:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'C:\\Users\\we\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'C:\\Users\\we\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this. It says that the command is not recognized but I do not know where to edit this command. 
This is the Android.mk file:

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#include the .mk files
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/celt_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/silk_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus_sources.mk

MY_MODULE_DIR       := opustool

LOCAL_MODULE        := $(MY_MODULE_DIR)

#float point sources
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_FLOAT)
OPUS_SOURCES += $(OPUS_SOURCES_FLOAT)
#ARM build
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_ARM)
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_ARM)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
$(CELT_SOURCES) $(SILK_SOURCES) $(OPUS_SOURCES)

LOCAL_LDLIBS        := -lm -llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk/float \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/celt
LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wnested-externs -Wshadow
LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -DNULL=0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -DOPUS_BUILD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -O2 -std=gnu99 -g 
#LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      := -DBSD=1
#LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      += -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and this is the Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI  := all
APP_CFLAGS := -std=gnu99
```

Comment: I think your real problem is this `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null`

Comment: Why not just use the newer [`externalNativeBuild`](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) instead?

Comment: Do you have a `Application.mk` along with `Android.mk` inside your `jni` folder? If yes please post its contents in your question.

Comment: @pleft I have posted Application.mk and Android.mk

Comment: @Michael why use the newer externalNativeBuild?

Comment: @Michael why use the newer externalNativeBuild?

Comment: Because that's the method suggested by Google for the most recent gradle plugin versions, and you won't have to worry about invoking `ndk-build` yourself.

Comment: Did you mean CMake by newer externalNativeBuild? What steps are needed. Please guide me.

Comment: @pleft how to solve the problem?

Comment: Check this Gradle and try to comply with it https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni/app